# C++ inserting in map() is taking a long time

Tags: c++, dictionary, object, pointers, insert

I have a `map` with types `<int, foo*>` which I am populating from a database. `int` is a unique key so before populating I am checking if key is already in map if not than a new object of type `foo` is created and inserted in map.

The `foo` class also has another map as attribute with types `<int, float>` which also needs to be populated from the database. I have the below code which is supposedly simple:

```
std::map<int, foo> MAP;

while(getline(infile, line))
{ //reading records in data file
    string item;
    stringstream ss(line);
    vector<string> splittedString;

    int a = stoi(splittedString[0]); // cells after splitting data
    int b = stoi(splittedString[1]);
    float c = stof(splittedString[2]);


    if (MAP.find(a) == MAP.end())
    {
        foo f = foo();
        MAP.insert({a, &f});
        f.fooMap.insert({b, c/100});
    }
    else
    {
        foo* f = MAP.at(a);
        f->fooMap.insert({b, c/100});
    }
}
```

This is taking a ridiculous amount of time to compute. There are about 50,000 records but that should not take forever. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong since I am somewhat rusty with c++.

I know I have some redundancy when creating the foo object and I think a more efficient way of doing the above is the below 'incorrect' code:

```
while(getline(infile, line))
{//reading records in data file
    string item;
    stringstream ss(line);
    vector<string> splittedString;

    int a = stoi(splittedString[0]); //cells after splitting data
    int b = stoi(splittedString[1]);
    float c = stof(splittedString[2]);

    foo f = *MAP[a];        
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        f = foo();
        MAP.insert({a, &f});

    }    
    f->fooMap.insert({b, c/100});
}
```

## update

if I use `MAP<int, foo>` instead of `MAP<int, foo*>` (and arranging the insertion code accordingly), the code works normally. So I am doing something wrong with pointers. what is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Do you know what does `MAP({a, &f});` do and why? What is `MAP`?

Comment: map is a c++ map http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ maybe I should make it more clear by inserting the namespace before it.

Comment: Profile? What are the costs of splitting and calculating c? You could just `insert()` the value, which returns a boolean that tells you if it is already present. You can also use `emplace()` to not construct the value until it is inserted, but this is somewhat difficult to use effectively in c++11. In c++17 use `try_emplace()`, but if you want to save the effort of calculating c and foo() you would need to invent a wrapper class that can be constructed by splittedString[2] or foo() respectively.

Comment: Don't use `<int, foo*>`.  Instead use `<int, std::unique_ptr<foo>>`.

Comment: @user7331538, I doubt `MAP({a, &f});` or `MAP(a)` is valid syntax.

Comment: Please have a look at the [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) interface again. There is no call operator (`operator()`) defined for `std::map`. Therefore, your  `MAP(a)` is either wrong, or it does not do what you expect it to do...

Comment: @vahancho MAP(a) should have been MAP.find(a) and MAP({a, &f}) should have been MAP.insert({a, &f}). My mistake. Just edited the question.

Comment: @user7331538 Please post your compiler options.  If you're timing a "debug" or unoptimized build, then your findings are meaningless.  Any question that has "why is C++ slow?" or "Why is C++ slower than...?" requires you to post the information concerning how you built your application.

Comment: How do you compile the code? With which optimizations? Please create a proper [mcve] - including the benchmark.

Comment: Storing pointers to local variables is not a good idea.

Comment: `MAP.insert({a, &f});`, and since `f` is a local variable, to, at the very least, the `while(getline(infile, line))`, dereferencing such entry, on any subsequent iteration of the loop, is undefined behavior, due to the `f` being  destroyed at the end of each iteration.

Comment: In the code shown, `splittedString` as a size equal to 0 before used. Some code is missing?

Comment: @Damien some code is obviously missing since I have my own database that I am reading from

Comment: It makes more sense now! Still, you got a big error in your code. The lines `foo f = foo(); MAP.insert({a, &f});` produce a pointer to a deleted object. You probably should use smart pointers instead...

Comment: @jan.sende or maybe change MAP<int, foo*> to Map<int, foo> ?

Comment: Sure, but then your code is still wrong ;) `MAP.emplace(a, foo());` would be the right option. (`emplace` is probably a tiny bit faster than `insert` for your case.)

Comment: @user7331538 [There is no issue inserting 50000 items here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e50dd09c1ad5d1b2).  Again, post your compiler options.  All of these suggestions will be made null and void if it is discovered you are running an unoptimized build, and that is the reason for the slowness.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie in your case though foo object is not a pointer in the map. I just tried mine by inserting the object instead of a pointer and it worked well and fast. Inserting the pointer is what is making it so slow

Comment: @user7331538 Insering the pointer is making it have undefined behaviour. Reasoning about the performance of undefined code is pointless at best.

Comment: @jan.sende I think you are right. can you outline a solution that uses pointers or unique_ptr?

Comment: See my answer on how to do this with `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You code is a little bit more complicated than it needs to be. You should let `std::map` do the work instead of trying it yourself. What you want is the `.emplace` function of the container. It not only skips the insert if not necessary, but it also gives you the right entry to modify. For example, you could do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    //helper
    auto print = [](auto MAP) 
    {
        std::cout << "MAP:\n";
        for (auto && each : MAP)
            std::cout << each.first << "->" << each.second << '\n';
    };
    //work
    std::map<int, std::string> MAP;

    MAP.emplace(1,"").first->second = "one";
    MAP.emplace(2,"").first->second = "two";
    print(MAP);
    MAP.emplace(1,"").first->second = "three";
    print(MAP);
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
MAP:
1->one
2->two
MAP:
1->three
2->two
```

Of course, this has this weird `.first->second` syntax, but we can refactor it into a new lambda:

```
auto update = [](auto& MAP, auto index, auto entry) 
{
    MAP.emplace(index,"").first->second = entry;
};
```

which lets you write the following:

```
update(MAP, 1, "one");
update(MAP, 2, "two");
print(MAP);
update(MAP, 1, "three");
print(MAP);
```

**EDIT**

Because you asked for a `std::unique_ptr` solution, here is it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    //helper
    auto print = [](const auto& MAP) 
    {
        std::cout << "MAP:\n";
        for (auto && each : MAP)
            std::cout << each.first << "->" << *each.second.get() << '\n';
    };
    //work
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> MAP;

    auto update = [](auto& MAP, auto index, auto entry) 
    {
        *MAP.emplace(index, std::make_unique<std::string>()).first->second.get() = entry;
    };
    update(MAP, 1, "one");
    update(MAP, 2, "two");
    print(MAP);
    update(MAP, 1, "three");
    print(MAP);
}
```

It unfortunately gets a little bit unreadable and also annoying because `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied. (This is just the way it is implemented.)